# Can you move issues between Jira Projects

Tags: jira

Trying to figure out best way to setup Jira for cross-organizational project. We have a Continuous Delivery Program that will split off into separate backlogs to be worked by different teams based on Themes.

Wondering if we should setup one project to manage the overall high level project, and then different projects per theme of work that will be managed by the individual teams.

Are there ways multiple teams can work out of the same project but track their work separately (including if their work is Kan-Ban, Scrum-Ban or Sprint based?)

Comment: This site lives from questioning answering and accepting flow. That's what people drives to participate. Since you are new here please don't forget to accept an answer see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work for more details. But don't get my wrong it doesn't means you have to accept my answer ;)

Answer (score -1):

Regarding the question in the title. It's possible to move issues in `JIRA` from project to project. This feature is quite handy and you even can do bulk operations. See [Moving an issue](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/moving-an-issue-776997759.html) for more details.

Regarding structuring your projects. Out of the box there is no feature in `JIRA` to create such a workflow with projects and sub projects you have described.

A possible workaround could be using components as sub projects. 
In this case you would create a project which act as your high level project and divide this project into several components. For components you can add a lead, do versioning but you can not set security permissions based on components for example. So this is not a perfect solution and have indeed some limitations since components are not projects. But you have to evaluate this approach by yourself if it is sufficient for you.

Another option would be to use a plugin e.g. [Structure](http://almworks.com/structure/overview.html). I am pretty sure there are even more out there which promising to solve your problem. From my experience also using a plugin may be not the silver bullet you are expect. You have to evaluate it first if it really suits your workflow.

Answer (score -1):

For the scenario you describe, the issues that you start from are probably more high-level than the actual work that has to picked up in the separate teams.

What I find to work well, is to keep 1 project (ie. Opportunity Backlog) for the high level issue (ie. an Opportunity) and when an opportunity gets detailed out, just create issues in the projects of the teams that will work on them. You can still link those issues to the opportunity so people who look at it can see what is happening in each team.

Another option is to keep everything in 1 project, but to make the relevant issues show up on the board for the team that has to work on them. A board can list issues of multiple projects. You just need to update the JQL query for the board accordingly. For more details, [check the documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/configuring-filters-764477988.html). Note that working with sprints can get cumbersome if the same issues are listed on boards of multiple teams though. Best to configure things such that an issue is only displayed on the board of 1 team.

I wouldn't bother with moving issues too much. It's not a very user friendly action.